# mixed random variable from two Uniform random variables

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to create a mixed random variable from two Uniform random variables:

```
import sympy as sp
import sympy.stats as ss

x      = sp.symbols('x', real=True, positive=True)
mixed  = ss.Uniform('X',  10, 20) * sp.Rational(1, 3) + ss.Uniform('Y', 15, 30) * sp.Rational(2, 3)
d      = ss.density(mixed)(x).simplify()
```

I've been able to piece together a similar example with two Normal random variables, so I would think doing something like this with Uniform random variablew would then be trivial.

```
import sympy as sp
import sympy.stats as ss

x      = sp.symbols('x', real=True, positive=True)
mixed  = ss.Normal('X', 1, 1) * sp.Rational(1, 3) + ss.Normal('Y', 2, 1) * sp.Rational(2, 3)
d      = ss.density(mixed)(x).simplify()

display(d.subs(x, 1.5))
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Code runs fine for me, no errors encountered. I admit that the result is pretty ugly, but did you expect anything else? If so, what exactly did you expect? This might help to see whether there is an issue with `sympy` or simply some unimplemented functionality. Also, note that the `ss.density` of a Normal returns a function, whereas Uniform yields a piecewise object. Not sure why they did not implement Uniform to return a function with two heaviside functions, but this might explain some of the differences in behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I was taken aback by the ugliness of the result and I *assumed* I was doing something wrong. I'll work through it again now that it's daytime. Thanks also for pointing out that the result is a piecewise object.